# clone array CCSprite

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Advice please:
Cocos2d.
I have an array CCSprite:

```
movableSprites = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSArray *images = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"bird.png", @"cat.png", @"dog.png", @"turtle.png", nil];
        for(int i = 0; i < images.count; ++i) {
            NSString *image = [images objectAtIndex:i];
            CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:image];
            float offsetFraction = ((float)(i+1))/(images.count+1);
            sprite.position = ccp(winSize.width*offsetFraction, winSize.height/2);
            [self addChild:sprite];
            [movableSprites addObject:sprite];
        }
```

Create a clone of the array: MovableSprites2.
The second array is added to the scene .
I have a method: selectSpriteForTouch:

```
- (Void) selectSpriteForTouch: (CGPoint) touchLocation {
    CCSprite * newSprite = nil;
    for (CCSprite * sprite in movableSprites) {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint (sprite.boundingBox, touchLocation)) {
            newSprite = sprite;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (newSprite! = selSprite) {
        [selSprite stopAllActions];
        [selSprite runAction: [CCRotateTo actionWithDuration: 0.1 angle: 0 ]] ;
        CCRotateTo * rotLeft = [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration: 0.1 angle: -4.0];
        CCRotateTo * rotCenter = [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration: 0.1 angle: 0.0];
        CCRotateTo * rotRight = [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration: 0.1 angle: 4.0];
        CCSequence * rotSeq = [CCSequence actions: rotLeft, rotCenter, rotRight, rotCenter, nil];
        [newSprite runAction: [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction: rotSeq]];
        selSprite = newSprite;

    }
}
```

Whereby when you click on any CCSprite, the CCSprite starts to spin.
Please tell me how can I make, by clicking on one of the first array of CCSprite, appeared CCSprite with exactly the same picture of the second array , he began spinning CCSprite not from the first array and the second , which appeared ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a sprite that uses the same texture (picture) as an already existing sprite:

```
CCSprite* newSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:existingSprite.texture
                                             rect:existingSprite.textureRect];
```